# How can I add a CheckBox to the GridPane after the scene has already been loaded/shown?

Tags: java, javafx, checkbox, dynamic

I'm writing a program that sorts a list of Json objects and then formats/prints the data in each Json Object. I've created a GUI that allows the user to select which JSON Strings from the Json Object they would like to include in the final print.

To do this, I have a button for the user to press that loads a HashMap of String/Checkbox Pairs, where the string is the KEY_NAME of the respective JSON String. What I want to do is, after the scene has been loaded and the GUI shown, add the CheckBox's from the map to an existing GridPane in the scene.

I've tried the version below, and also tried it without re-adding the gpane to the AnchorPane. So far nothing has caused the scene to refresh. How can I accomplish this?

```
public void addCheckboxes(GridPane gpane, AnchorPane pane, Map<String, CheckBox> map){
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    int row = 1, col = 0;
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        gpane.add((CheckBox) pair.getValue(), col, row);

        pane.getChildren().add(gpane);

        row++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. But you'll need to post a [mcve] in order to make it clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You should also read [ask] a good question. What is going wrong? Are you getting any error messages? What are you hoping to have happen and what is happening instead?

Comment: The code you've posted results in a `duplicate children added` error, if the size of the map is 2 or larger; it'll do this even if the size is 1, if the `GridPane` is already a child of the `AnchorPane`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code demonstrates "How to add a CheckBox to the GridPane after the scene has already been loaded".
It is also [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which you can use as a reference for future questions<sup>(1)</sup>.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Button add = new Button("Add Check boxes");

        GridPane gpane = new GridPane();
        gpane.setHgap(10); gpane.setVgap(10);
        String[] strings = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
        add.setOnAction(e-> {
            addCheckboxes(gpane, strings, 3);
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(gpane);
        root.setBottom(add);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 150,150));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void addCheckboxes(GridPane gpane, String[] strings, int colums){
        int row = 0, col = 0;

        for(String s: strings){
            gpane.add(new CheckBox(s), col, row);
            col = ++col % colums;
            row = col == 0 ? ++row : row;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you need a map to reference the `CheckBox`s object, you can have `addCheckboxes` return such map:

```
private Map<String, CheckBox> addCheckboxes(GridPane gpane, String[] strings, int colums){

    Map<String, CheckBox> map = new HashMap<>();

    int row = 0, col = 0;
    for(String s: strings){
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(s);    
        gpane.add(checkBox, col, row);
        map.put(s, checkBox);

        col = ++col % colums;
        row = col == 0 ? ++row : row;
    }

    return map;
}
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> SO policy is: 
"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself..."